# Raspberry Pi and the USB to TTL Serial Cable on Mac

Tags: usb, serial, macos, serial-console

I've logged all my progress here [Raspberry Pi and the USB to TTL Serial Cable on Mac (unfinished)](https://gist.github.com/reggi/2ccc955a4a6ce119d64d).

`screen /dev/cu.PL2303-000013FA 115200`

Here's the errors that I'm getting

1. It just hangs with a empty terminal screen.
2. It errors / flashes `Cannot open line '/dev/cu.PL2303-000013FA' for R/W: Resource busy` and then lands on `Sorry, could not find a PTY.` then I get the command line back with a printed `[screen is terminating]` statement.
3. If I run it with `sudo` ie `sudo screen /dev/cu.PL2303-000013FA 115200` I get a completly different error `/dev/cu.PL2303-000013FA: ioctl TIOCEXCL failed: Resource busy`, then the blank terminal screen.

How do I resolve these issues, and get my raspberry pi working with the USB to TTL serial cable on OSX?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: You shouldn't connect the 5v (red) cable.

Comment: @lenik, errors imply I need assistance with said errors...

Comment: @Gerben I think it's completely irrelevant how I choose to power it. I'm not going through both power adapter and 5v. Why would that cause these errors?

Comment: @ThomasReggi Lenik does have a point. There is no *explicit* question here. While it is true that the errors *do imply* that you need help resolving said errors, you would be better off putting a simple one-line explicit question at the bottom of your question, something like **How do I resolve these issues?** or **What is causing these errors?**.

Comment: As long as you don't plug in both you're fine.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you have your RX and TX lines the wrong way round … [Connect to your Raspberry Pi with a Console Cable](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview "Connect to your Raspberry Pi with a Console Cable")

Comment: I personally use the CP2102 serial converter (we have about 30 of them at my 4 person work).  They are natively supported on windows/linux and the mac driver is the first result on google and they work super well.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the same issue and I tried a lot of different solutions with no avail. Three different drivers, different versions of OS X and different terminal programs.

In the end the problem proved to be much more easily solved than I thought. Double check your cabling. Make sure you've not plugged the RX and TX cables inversely. As soon as figured out that my USB-to-Serial cable had the colours green and white swapped, going agains the documentation, all was solved.

I hope it is as simple as that to you too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've tried every cable combination. But I'll try this! Thanks!

Comment: I just went through every combination (including the black wire, which should be ground). I realized the resource busy issue was because I wasn't' exiting the screen command properly and the process stays alive, then when you try to connect again it's busy.

Comment: I just installed NOOBS 1.4.1 (and Raspbian) and within `raspi-config` under `Advanced Options` I enabled both `SSH` and `Serial`. I'm still getting a blank `screen` regardless the orientation of the `white` and `green` wires.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to question #3, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu

If you want to test your uart connector by itself, connect tx to rx.  Then open your screen command.  Every key you type should appear back (echod back).  (note that it will only appear once, not twice).  When you remove the wire, characters will stop appearing.

My final advice is to checkout the CP2102.  For instance: [http://www.amazon.com/KEDSUM%C2%AE-CP2102-Module-Download-Converter/dp/B009T2ZR6W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009T2ZR6W)